# ionic cordova compile ios . Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

I encountered the same problem.

Version information: node -v : v7.10.0 npm -v : 4.6.1 cordova -v :7.0.1 angular/cli: 1.0.4 ionic -v : 3.3.0

The error message：

> cordova compile ios
>   ✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova compile ios (exit code 1):

```
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/cordova/build-extras.xcconfig'
```

gegaozhaodeiMac:SengledLife-0 gegaozhao$ sudo ionic cordova compile ios

> cordova compile ios
>   ✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova compile ios (exit code 1):

```
    (truncated) ... :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS"
        /usr/sbin/chown -RH root:wheel /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SengledLife-ewbxwhbmxfyrqvehvjnxjlgxqyej/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SengledLife/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libCordova.a

    SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SengledLife-ewbxwhbmxfyrqvehvjnxjlgxqyej/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SengledLife/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libCordova.a
        cd /Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS"
        /bin/chmod -RH u+w,go-w,a+rX /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SengledLife-ewbxwhbmxfyrqvehvjnxjlgxqyej/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SengledLife/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libCordova.a

    === BUILD TARGET SengledLife OF PROJECT SengledLife WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

    Check dependencies
    Signing for "SengledLife" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
    warning: no rule to process file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SLLivePlaySdk.framework' of type wrapper.framework for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.slliveplayer/SLLivePlayBundle.bundle' of type wrapper.plug-in for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.snapNetwork/cloud' of type file for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ElementScanBulbCodeVIewSdk.framework' of type wrapper.framework for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/notice.gif' of type image.gif for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/ScanBulbCodeViewController.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/SlScanNavigationController.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture armv7
    warning: no rule to process file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SLLivePlaySdk.framework' of type wrapper.framework for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.slliveplayer/SLLivePlayBundle.bundle' of type wrapper.plug-in for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.snapNetwork/cloud' of type file for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ElementScanBulbCodeVIewSdk.framework' of type wrapper.framework for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/notice.gif' of type image.gif for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/ScanBulbCodeViewController.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture arm64
    warning: no rule to process file '/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/SengledLife/Plugins/com.sengled.zxing.barcodescanner/SlScanNavigationController.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture arm64
    Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
            Check dependencies
    (1 failure)
    Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,SengledLife.xcworkspace,-scheme,SengledLife,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,SengledLife.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/gegaozhao/Desktop/SengledLife-0/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

--- The above is my detailed information, if there is a good solution, please share, thanks

Comment: You need to open the iOS Project in Xcode and assign it a development team/provisioning profile

Comment: Please provide some info on what you tried to do to solve the problem. By searching for some of the error messages like `** ARCHIVE FAILED **` You will most likely find some pointers on what you could try.